# Reusing a single modal to display dynamic content for a number of modules in angular js

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I'm looking to create a stateful app that uses a common modal for a number of modules. On clicking items in a menu, the modal window should open and then I'm hoping to populate the modal with dynamic data based on the button that was pressed.

So for example, if I click 'Users' I would want the modal to pop up and then using angular, I want to populate the modal with all the users

I've been playing around but haven't managed to get very far with it.

Here is the body of my html:

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-center" id="js-navbar-collapse">

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

            <li class="active">
                <a href="#/users"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Modal">
                    <div class="users_icon">&nbsp;</div>
                    <br>
                    <p>Users</p>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a ng-href="#/settings"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Modal">
                    <div class="settings_icon">&nbsp;</div>
                    <br>
                    <p>Settings</p>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="modal fade" id="Modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="ModalLabel">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">

                <div class="modal-content"  ui-view="modal" autoscroll="false">

                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

and my js so far:

```
'use strict';

angular
.module('myApp', [
    'ui.router',
    'js-data'
])

.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/calendar');

    $stateProvider
        .state("Modal", {
            views:{
                "modal": {
                    templateUrl: "views/modal.html"
                }
            },
            abstract: true
        })
        .state("Modal.addtask", {
            views:{
                "modal": {
                    templateUrl: "views/modals/addtask.html"
                }
            }
        });

})
```

I would like to be able to click an item in the menu, use the normal bootstrap javascript to open the modal dialog and then the modal to be populated by angular with dynamic data relative to the menu item clicked. I can't use angular ui as I am using SCSS for styling and it only supports LESS. Any help would be very appreciated.

At the moment, the modal pops up but then I can't get the data to populate in the modal

Comment: Is there a specific question you would like to have answered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do this by utilising sticky states as described here: http://christopherthielen.github.io/ui-router-extras/#/sticky